# Installing Bitcoin on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, bitcoin

I've been using Ubuntu for a little over a year now and have gotten fairly comfortable with the UI.  The one case I've had trouble on was recently trying to install bit coin on my 13.10 computer.  When I open up the deb file and it takes me to the software center where there should be an install button there's something about libdb4.8++.  Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the PPA not just download a deb file. That's why they redirect you here https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/bitcoin wich has the instructions to add the PPA.

https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html

easy peasy :) Just follow the instructions.